# Installing DescribeDisplay R package

Tags: r

Several attempts made to install rggobi R package but always fail because of DescribeDisplay package.

As mentioned, the following command is used to install DescribeDisplay

```
install.packages("DescribeDisplay", dep=T)

package 'DescribeDisplay' is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

Also used chooseCRANmirror() to select different mirror but this fails too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescribeDisplay/index.html),I found

> Package ‘DescribeDisplay’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
>
> This package has been archived: it had check WARNINGs after a ggplot2
>   update. These WARNINGs were not fixed even after reminders.

This explains why you can not install the package in the way you tried. You can
download an archived version and install the package from the downloaded local zip file.

Comment: I don't find a Windows archive of DescribeDisplay. Anyway it seems not to work https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggobi/ZF3E9o0v0N0